# Get a list of all the arguments a constructor takes

Tags: haxe

Is it possible to get a list of all the arguments a constructor takes?
With the names and types of the parameters?

I want to automatically check the values of a JSON are good to use for building their equivalent as a class instance.

Preferably without macros... I have build a few, but I still find them quiet confusing.

Must work with neko and JS, if that maters.

Thanks.

Comment: There's `haxe.macro.Context.getType()` which gives you access to a list of parameters, but that's a macro. Can't think of a way to do it otherwise in Neko and JS. Flash has a built-in function for it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look at [Runtime Type Information](http://haxe.org/manual/cr-rtti.html) (rtti)

> **From the Haxe Manual:** The Haxe compiler generates runtime type information (RTTI) for classes that are annotated or extend classes that are annotated with the `@:rtti` metadata. This information is stored as a XML string in a static field `__rtti` and can be processed through [haxe.rtti.XmlParser](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/rtti/XmlParser.html). The resulting structure is described in [RTTI structure](http://haxe.org/manual/cr-rtti-structure.html).

Alternative; If you want to go with macros, this might be a good start
http://code.haxe.org/category/macros/add-parameters-as-fields.html